# android download large file with php

Tags: php, android

Hi guys I want to create android application that download files from database server,
i found a lot of examples like this one:

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fileUploadDownload {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws URISyntaxException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        uploadFileToServer("video.mp4","http://upload.php");
        downloadFileFromServer("video.mp4","http://video.mp4");
    }

    /**
     * This function upload the large file to server with other POST values.
     * @param filename
     * @param targetUrl
     * @return
     */
    public static String uploadFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
        String response = "error";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = filename;
        String urlServer = targetUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String token = "anyvalye";
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Token\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + token.length() + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(token + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String taskId = "anyvalue";
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"TaskID\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + taskId.length() + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(taskId + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String connstr = null;
            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UploadFile\";filename=\""
                    + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            System.out.println("Image length " + bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("Server Response Code " + " " + serverResponseCode);
            System.out.println("Server Response Message "+ serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }else
            {
                response = "false";
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();

            connection.getInputStream();
            //for android InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            int ch;
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
                b.append( (char)ch );
            }

            String responseString = b.toString();
            System.out.println("response string is" + responseString); //Here is the actual output

            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            System.out.println("Send file Exception" + ex.getMessage() + "");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * This function download the large files from the server
     * @param filename
     * @param urlString
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void downloadFileFromServer(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
            {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            if (fout != null)
                    fout.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

but i can't understand how to connect it with server via php, i mean the link path when i want to change it to link take me to php file in server which help to complete the process of downloading files from database, all examples i found contain the java section only without the php
help me please if you have any examples like i need thanks.